# How to calculate number of digits on huge number? C++

Tags: c++, logic, pow

so the problem I have is that there is two integers (a, b) that is in [1, 10^16] interval and I need to do find out how many digits will number a^b have? Those numbers are too big for saving them on single variables, and if I write them on Array it would take a lot of time.

Is there a way to count the number a^b number of digits with some kind of formula or any simpler way then Arrays?

Comment: 10 base logarithm will give the number of digits.

Comment: Are you looking for a somewhat accurate, in the ballpark, number or a precise number?

Comment: Well only thing I need is number of digits, actual result of a^b is not important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

karakfa has it right.

The base-`k` logarithm of a number `n`, rounded up to the nearest whole number, will give you the number of digits required to represent `n` in base `k`.

EDIT: as pointed out in comments, it should not be rounded up, but rounded down and then incremented by one. This accounts for round powers of 10 having an extra digit.

If your number is `a^b` then take the base-10 logarithm, `log a^b` and use the laws of logarithms to simplify as `b log a`. Note that this simplification happens inside the `ceiling` function so the simplification is valid. Computing `log a` should not be an issue (it will be between 0 and 16) and `b` is known. Just make sure to round after multiplying, not before.

Note that limited precision of floating-point numbers may introduce some errors into this method. If the true value of `b x log a` is different from the nearest floating-point representation of `b x log a` in such a way that they fall on different sides of an integer, the method fails. You can possibly detect when you are close to this condition and remediate it somehow.

Comment: @GaBoKaS See Slava's comment on karakfa's answer: it should be `floor() + 1` instead of `ceiling` to account for even powers of 10.

Comment: BTW, it will be not easy to calculate it on 32-bit system. So 64-bit system is required.

Answer (score 6):

after fixing the one-off error suggested in the comments

number of digits of `a^b = floor( b * log(a) ) + 1`

Comment: I think it should be `floor() + 1`, otherwise it will give incorrect values for 1 10 100 etc.

Comment: for powers of 10, the value will be integer, so `ceil(n)==n`

Comment: Right so log(1) == 0, `ceil` of that is also 0, does it mean it takes 0 digits to store 1? log(10)==1 etc

Answer (score 0):

You could use a library that supports arbitrarily large numbers, like [GMP](https://gmplib.org) .

The core C++ language itself offers no types to work with such large numbers. So either you use a pre-existing library or write one yourself (I suggest the former - don't re-invent the wheel).

Comment: It's all about calculating amount of digits without having to actually store the number in memory. It even can be that it's not writeable even using 100% of your RAM. Anyway you'll probably need GMP to store a number representing amount of digits :D

Comment: Is there some kind of other way that does not require downloading anything? :)